# UIAlertController not working

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Initialize Alert View
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet connection", message: "Please Connect to Internet", preferredStyle: .Alert)

    let EXITAction = UIAlertAction(title: "EXIT", style: .Destructive) {(action) in
        //...
        exit(0)

    }
    alertController.addAction(EXITAction)

    self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true) {
        // ...
    }


}
```

I'm trying to use this for onLoad if use click then exit.
but nothing happen. Please help

(I am quite new in programming)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to move your code to present the `UIAlertController` to the `viewDidAppear` method.

If you put code that modifies the user interface in the `viewDidLoad`, it won't be applied to the views because the view controller is still loading.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a function like follows and you can call it in your `viewDidAppear()` method as `alert("Message String")`.

```
func alert(info:String) {
        let popUp = UIAlertController(title: "Title", message: info, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        popUp.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK!", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: {alertAction in
            popUp.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        }))
        self.presentViewController(popUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```